# Will Lockheed Martin Flight Services send me ACAS, EasyActivate™, and other text messages if I file my flight plan through ForeFlight Mobile?

Tags: flight-planning, avionics, lockheed-martin

[ForeFlight Mobile](https://www.foreflight.com/products/foreflight-mobile/) users who file flight plans without being authenticated to CSC DUATS will effectively [file through Lockheed Martin Flight Services](http://blog.foreflight.com/2014/05/12/rogerback-notifications-from-atc/) (LMFS).

Considering that the LMFS route does not require my personal  [1800wxbrief.com](https://www.1800wxbrief.com/) credentials (unlike filing through CSC DUATS), will additional services connected to my LMFS profile such as [Adverse Condition Alerting Service (ACAS)](http://www.lockheedmartin.com/us/news/press-releases/2012/october/isgs-afss-acas-1011.html), EasyActivate™/EasyClose™, Close Reminders, ATC Notices, and Surveillance Enhanced Search and Rescue (SE-SAR) be accessible through my mobile phone?

In other words, will Lockheed associate my ForeFlight flight plan with my LMFS profile in order to send me text messages with information about TFRs, links to open and close flight plans, and so on?

Comment: Is it still about aviation... with trademarks everywhere?

Comment: @mins  Certainly looks like it to me, yes.  Part of being a good pilot is knowing how to use the tools you have available and understanding their limitations, and things like DUATS are ForeFlight are tools that lots of pilots use.  This isn't exactly promoting Joe's Little Flying App; I doubt Lockheed Martin needs to come here for "free advertising" of their services.  Looks like a valid question to me.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but the simplest thing may be to try it if you're already an FF user, or [ask them](https://www.foreflight.com/support/contact/) if you're not. I didn't see anything relevant in their FAQ.

Comment: PIREP: I filed through FF today on a quick out-and-back XC. The plan didn’t show up in my plans on 1800wxbrief.com, and I did not receive the text messages as when I file through Lockheed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on my personal experience, the answer is NO (as of the time of writing). I use both systems regularly, and have discovered the two do not share flight plans at the user account level. ForeFlight uses its own account (and not individual user accounts) to interact with Lockheed Martin Flight Services. Because of this, it appears that LMFS has no way of knowing which user account is associated with a flight plan filed through ForeFlight.

Identifying data within the flight plan itself (i.e., name and phone) are not processed by the filing system, merely stored for later retrieval if needed. I mention this because LMFS can (upon request) associate tail numbers with a phone number, so that when you call them on 800-WX-BRIEF your profile comes up on their screen automatically (though I have found this to be less useful than one might think).

In order to use the services you have identified, you will need to file your flight plan directly on the LMFS web site (and have your notification settings configured properly).

With that said, all of these functions (with the exception SE-SAR), have been available directly within ForeFlight for some time:

ACAS/ATC notices - if configured by the user, sent via push notification (http://blog.foreflight.com/2014/11/24/6-5-brings-flight-notifications-and-notam-advisor/)

EasyActivate/EasyClose - flight plans can be amended/canceled/activated/closed within the File & Brief window (http://blog.foreflight.com/tag/flight-plan-filing/#attachment_4045)

Close reminder - sent via push notification (https://support.foreflight.com/hc/en-us/articles/205052928-What-are-push-notifications-)

Over the past couple of years, ForeFlight has been aggressively working towards tighter integration with LMFS, so I would expect additional functionality to be forthcoming (purely speculative, since they are very tight-lipped about upcoming enhancements).

UPDATE:

It looks like LMFS now offers integrated services with a number of providers (but not ForeFlight). My guess is ForeFlight doesn't allow it because it was already offering the same services and now needs to figure out a way to ensure users don't get duplicate messages:

[image: LMFS Service Provider Authorization screen]

Comment: Hello, my name is Daniel and I work for ForeFlight, your comment is accurate as of the time of this comment. Right now we do not integrate with Lockheed's "user account mechanism", for lack of a better phrase. Stay tuned!